# tomboy-ng starts but hangs before showing any pages. Was fine in 23.04

Tags: 23.10, tomboy

Tomboy-ng worked fine in ubuntu 23.04.  In 23.10, tomboy-ng v. 0.36a emits "QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread", brings up the system tray icon, will show correct menu of pages, but it hangs when you select a page to view.

Answer (score 0):

Read https://github.com/tomboy-notes/tomboy-ng/wiki/Bugs-and-Known-Issues#qt5-and-wayland:

Define QT_QPA_PLATFORM as suggested.
(e.g. $ QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb tomboy-ng)

Comment: Well, it's not all that simple.  I can get close to the original behavior by modifying the tomboy-ng desktop file, like this - Exec=QT_PLATFORM=wayland tomboy-ng %f. See the tomboy-ng wiki. But there are still glitches, I think.